# Show Download progress in a Recyclerview in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, android-download-manager

I am currently working on app where you can download video files. I am using Download manager for downloading files and everything is working fine as the files are being downloaded properly and I can see the progress of downloading in my notifications. Now I want to show those downloading files in another class (containing recyclerview) with the progress. So what should i do to implement this module?

```
  String urlDownload = mUrl;
        String filename = mUrl.substring(mUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        Log.i("onLoadResource()", "url = " + mUrl + "\n" + filename);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlDownload));

    request.setDescription("Testando");
    request.setTitle("Download");
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);

    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);

    final ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            boolean downloading = true;

            while (downloading) {

                DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                q.setFilterById(downloadId);

                Cursor cursor = manager.query(q);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    downloading = false;
                }

                final int dl_progress = (int) ((double)bytes_downloaded / (double)bytes_total * 100f);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        mProgressBar.setProgress((int) dl_progress);

                    }
                });


                cursor.close();
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: just broadcast the download percentage to that class.. and update the progress bar of recycler in that activity

Comment: okay i understand thanks but how to add multiple files in recyclerview adapter give me some guidance please

Comment: how to set broadcast for download percentage in that class guide me please

Comment: I'm with this problem over 1.5 years. No one in StackOverflow answers this topic. Even, Google couldnt help

Comment: I'm stuck at the same problem. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain a variable for progress in the data model you are using for each RecyclerViewItem. When you receive an update on progress, update the dataset you are using and after that call `notifyItemChanged(mPos)` or `notifyItemRangeChanged()` to notify the adapter of the same. `notifyItemChanged(mPos)` triggers `onBindVieHolder` for corresponding position even if it's currently not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some general advice.

You can update a `RecyclerView` row by calling `notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount, Object payload)`. This will call `onBindViewHolder(FeedBaseViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads)` in your adapter where you can update a row with a progress bar.

In the payload you can pass your desired values perspective with your requirements like start progress action, update progress, stop progress.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers which suggest using `notifyItemChanged()` gave me 3 big problems:

1. It needlessly updates the entire ViewHolder and all the child views,
2. It creates endless annoying animations as you scroll through the list while updates are being displayed
3. It shows progress updates on random (undeserving/incorrect) ViewHolders

What solved all of these problems for me was using callbacks to update the specific views relevant to the progress. My solution is in Kotlin because A) that is what I made it in, B) it was made to make problems like these easy, and C) the OP doesn't specify Java as the language.

The PRDownload library makes this somewhat easier by having a built-in callback system which invokes on every response/update - something which `DownloadManager` does not have. To use `DownloadManager`, all you would have to do is create a timer (maybe `WorkManager`) to query the `DownloadManager` database and get the download progress at some regular interval and invoke the callbacks with the progress.

Dependency for PRDownload:

```
implementation "com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.6.0"
```

## Adapter

```
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.downloader.Error
import com.downloader.OnDownloadListener
import com.downloader.OnProgressListener
import com.downloader.PRDownloader
import com.downloader.Progress

val mutableMapOfIDToProgressListenerCallback: MutableMap<Int, MyDownloadProgressListener> =
    mutableMapOf()

class RecyclerViewAdapter(private val dataSet: List<ListItem>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        lateinit var listItem: ListItem
        val percentDownloaded = itemView.findViewById<TextView?>(R.id.percent_downloaded)
        fun setUpdateViewLambda() {
            mutableMapOfIDToProgressListenerCallback[listItem.id]?.setLabmda {
                percentDownloaded?.text = toPercent(it).toString()
            }
        }

        fun removeUpdateViewLambda() {
            mutableMapOfIDToProgressListenerCallback[listItem.id]?.setLabmda {}
        }

        init {
            view.setOnClickListener { //to demonstrate downloads
                Thread { //use coroutines instead
                        downloadItem(
                            listItem,
                            adapterPosition,
                            this@RecyclerViewAdapter,
                            "https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-6.9.1-bin.zip", //insert your download here
                            view.context.getExternalFilesDir(null)!!.absolutePath,
                            "a${listItem.id}.zip"
                        )
                }.start()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: ViewHolder) {
        holder.setUpdateViewLambda()
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: ViewHolder) {
        holder.removeUpdateViewLambda() //remove callback so that recycled viewholder doesn't undeservingly get updates
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val listItem = dataSet[position]

        //perform your binding

        holder.listItem = listItem
        holder.percentDownloaded?.text = listItem.percentDownloaded.toString()
        holder.setUpdateViewLambda()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataSet.size
    }
}

data class ListItem(
    val id: Int, //a value that uniquely represents this list item
    var percentDownloaded: Byte //can only ever be between 0-100, so no need for Int
)

class MyDownloadProgressListener : OnProgressListener {
    lateinit var listItem: ListItem
    private var updateView: (progress: Progress) -> Unit = {}
    fun setLabmda(lambda: (progress: Progress) -> Unit) {
        updateView = lambda
    }

    override fun onProgress(progress: Progress?) {
        Log.d("Adapter", "Progress object: $progress")
        if (progress != null) {
            val toPercent = toPercent(progress)
            Log.d("Adapter", "Percent received: $toPercent")
            listItem.percentDownloaded = toPercent
            updateView(progress)
        }
    }
}

fun downloadItem(
    listItem: ListItem,
    adapterPosition: Int,
    adapter: RecyclerViewAdapter,
    url: String,
    dirPath: String,
    filename: String
) {
    val listener = MyDownloadProgressListener()
    mutableMapOfIDToProgressListenerCallback[listItem.id] = listener
    listener.listItem = listItem
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post { adapter.notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition)/*bind listener to ViewHolder*/ }

    PRDownloader
        .download(url, dirPath, filename)
        .build()
        .setOnProgressListener(listener)
        .setOnCancelListener {
                mutableMapOfIDToProgressListenerCallback.remove(listItem.id)
        }
        .start(object : OnDownloadListener {
            override fun onDownloadComplete() {
                mutableMapOfIDToProgressListenerCallback.remove(listItem.id)
            }

            override fun onError(error: Error?) {
                mutableMapOfIDToProgressListenerCallback.remove(listItem.id)
            }
        }
    )
}

fun toPercent(progress: Progress) =
    (100 * (progress.currentBytes / progress.totalBytes.toDouble())).toInt().toByte()
```